# How to create a new workspace through script?

Tags: scripting, rhel, workspaces

I usually create new workspace whenever i start a new activity. Since i work on multiple task, i want to isolate them from one another.
So every time i create a workspace, i have to do some set of same work.
**So, i am looking for a way to create the workspace through script**, so that i can automate this.

Just with a single command I should be able to create a new workspace and i want to do some set of tasks - like creating a new directory and pulling code base in that and trigger the build.

I know how to do rest of the task - ie creating the new directory, pulling code base, and triggering the build. Only thing I am unsure is how to create a new workspace through script.

*Operating System: RedRat*

Answer (score 0):

man [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/):

> ```
>    -n N   Change the number of desktops to N (a non-negative integer).
> ```